# Remove duplication's from my DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my controller i am returning list of my object with specific property:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<MyObject> list = db.MyObjects.Where(x => x.family == "Web").ToList();
    ViewBag.Files = new SelectList(list, "Id", "protocol");
    return View();
}
```

This is my object:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string fileName { get; set; }
    public string browser { get; set; }    
    public string protocol { get; set; }    
    public string family { get; set; }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@Html.DropDownList("File", new SelectList(ViewBag.Files, "Id", "protocol_site"), "Select webmail site", new { style = "vertical-align:middle;" })
```

And i try to made 2 changes with no succeed:

1. Remove all the duplication protocol from my `DropDownList`for exapmle if i have 10 objects : 9 is doc protocol and 1 pdf i wand to see in my `DropDownList` only 2 items: DOC and PDF and not all the 10 items.
2. Sort this `DropDownList` in alphabet order

Comment: The duplicate protocol has the same Id or not?

Comment: Different id, is it matter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Dreamcatcher mentioned in his answer, you should pass already prepared collection to `SelectList` constructor and use linq for these tasks. For `Distinct` linq method you will need to create custom comparer, which will compare objects by protocol field:

```
public sealed class MyObjectByProtocolComparer: IEqualityComparer<MyObject>
{
    public bool Equals(MyObject x, MyObject y)
    {
        return x.protocol.Equals(y.protocol);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyObject obj)
    {
        return obj.protocol.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

This is rather simple implementation, you might need to check for null values. After that use it in your linq query:

```
var list = db.MyObjects.Where(x => x.family == "Web").ToArray();
list = list.Distinct(new MyObjectByProtocolComparer())
           .OrderBy(x => x.fileName)
           .ToArray();
```

Comment: Get an error: Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[ApplicationMyObjectsMVC.Models.MyObject] Distinct[MyObject](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[ApplicationMyObjectsMVC.Models.MyObject], System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1[ApplicationMyObjectsMVC.Models.MyObject])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Try the updated version. `Distinct` step shouldn't be translated via LINQ to Entities, but should work with already received items in code.

Comment: Convert to array is it necessary? Could you try without convert to array. For example: 
`List<MyObject> list = db.MyObjects.Where(x => x.family == "Web").ToList();
list = list.Distinct(new MyObjectByProtocolComparer()).OrderBy(x => x.fileName).ToList();`

Comment: It is necessary to execute linq query: perform `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()`. I've chosen `.ToArray()` because following code doesn't require `List` class functionality, just collection storage

Answer (score 1):

You should add second line in your code. However i am not sure correct spelling, i did not use VS. Also if Disctinct does not work correctly, you should write Comparer.

```
List<MyObject> list = db.MyObjects.Where(x => x.family == "Web").ToList();
list= list.OrderBy(x => x.fileName).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Where should i put it ?

Comment: Get an error: Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[AutomationMyObjectsMVC.Models.MyObject] Distinct[MyObject](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[AutomationMyObjectsMVC.Models.MyObject], System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1[AutomationMyObjectsMVC.Models.MyObject])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the guidelines in this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx so that you can call linq Distinct

Comment: It's a bad idea to override `Equals()` method for whole class to solve  this particular case. It's better to write specific comparer.

Comment: For me specific compares make sense when you need to have multiple comparison strategies or when I don't get to modify the class in question, forcing me to use IEqualityComparer. Can you please share any good reads on this why you made that point?

Comment: I actualy mean multiple specific comparison strategies vs default one in my comment. Class `MyObject` has `id` field which might be unique and identify the object. So default comparison by `protocol` field can mislead you.